# How to parse nested Json Array in retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json

The parsing is successful but problem is ,it is taking loggedinClients only,ActiveClients not getting in retrofit , how can we parse array under array and with no object name?

```
{
"status": 200,
"success": true,
"messages": "",
"result": [
    [
        {
            "LoggedinClients": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ActiveClients": 0
        }
    ]
  ]
}
```

partly Related Code:

```
public class OnlineInfoResponse {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<List<OnlineInfoLoggedInResult>> lstLists = null;

public List<List<OnlineInfoLoggedInResult>> getLstLoggedIn() {
    return lstLists;
}

public void setLstLists(List<List<OnlineInfoLoggedInResult>> lstLists) {
    this.lstLists = lstLists;
}
```

OnlineInfoLoggedInResult.java

```
public class OnlineInfoLoggedInResult {

 @SerializedName("LoggedinClients")
 @Expose
 private int loggedinClients;


 public int getLoggedinClients() {
    return loggedinClients;
 }

 public void setLoggedinClients(int loggedinClients) {
    this.loggedinClients = loggedinClients;
 }

 @SerializedName("ActiveClients")
 @Expose
 private int activeClients;

 public int getActiveClients() {
    return activeClients;
 }

 public void setActiveClients(int activeClients) {
    this.activeClients = activeClients;
 }

}
```

this i got parsing from jsonschema.I am having problem in nested jsonarray.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate the following POJO

```
public class YourPojoName {
 private float status;
 private boolean success;
 private String messages;
 List <List< Object> > result = new ArrayList < ArrayList<Object> > ();


 // Getter Methods 

 public float getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public boolean getSuccess() {
  return success;
 }

 public String getMessages() {
  return messages;
 }

 // Setter Methods 

 public void setStatus(float status) {
  this.status = status;
 }

 public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
  this.success = success;
 }

 public void setMessages(String messages) {
  this.messages = messages;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class abbb {


    @Expose
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<List<Result>> result;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("messages")
    private String messages;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("success")
    private boolean success;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    private int status;

    public List<List<Result>> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<List<Result>> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(String messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public static class Result {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("LoggedinClients")
        private int LoggedinClients;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("ActiveClients")
        private int active_clients;

          //genetrate getter setter
    }
}
```

Comment: you had done same as mine then how can i find active client?I am only getting loggedinclient